# How to perform synchronous requests in the queue from some users?

Tags: php, sql

Russian Community unfortunately did not help me. I appeal to you, if you allow.

There is a function to which there can be several synchronous requests. The principle should be such that the user gets on the page creates an entry. The ideal order should be such

```
+------+------+
| user |parent|
+------+------+
|     2|     1|
+------+------+
|     3|     2|
+------+------+
|     4|     3|
+------+------+
|     5|     4|
+------+------+
|     6|     5|
+------+------+
```

But I have it:

```
+------+------+
| user |parent|
+------+------+
|     2|     1|
+------+------+
|     3|     1|
+------+------+
|     4|     1|
+------+------+
|     5|     2|
+------+------+
|     6|     2|
+------+------+
```

I attempt use it:

```
DB::beginTransaction();
$activate->activate($us_id, $request->input('tarif'));
DB::commit();
```

How to make so that the next transaction did not begin, the previous will not end yet?